# Maui Entry Id gives a guid instead of the name

Tags: c#, .net-maui

I'm working on an Android Maui app.
I have all my Xaml Entry fields named.
I programmatically create Unfocused events for each Entry and they all point to the same Unfocused function.
If the sender.id is for a certain field name then I perform some validation on it.
When I get the value of the sender.id field I get a guid.
When I inspect the sender during debug I get the field name.

```
public async void Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    var entry = (Entry)sender;
    var fieldName = entry.Id.ToString(); // this returns a guid
}
```

and here's my Xaml

```
    <Entry Text="{Binding StorageLocation}"
           x:Name="txtStorageLocation"
           StyleId="StorageLocation"
           Placeholder="{Binding LocationOrBinPlaceholder}"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="20"/>
```

I'm expecting the sender.Id to be "txtStorageLocation"

Comment: Name != Id: `x:Name` is not part of the Entry class and you're confusing it with the `Id`, which indeed is a GUID. What you are trying to achieve is not possible like that, unfortunately. If you want to be able to name your Entry, you will need to write your own extended version of the Entry class.

Comment: the debugger shows the field name so I had hoped I could somehow look it up by guid.  But I think extending the Entry class would be a cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a **Name** or **Identifier** on an `Entry` in order to process the `Unfocused` event, then you could implement your own derived `NamedEntry` class like this:

**Inherited class: NamedEntry.cs**

```cs
public class NamedEntry : Entry
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
}
```

**Register handler in MauiProgram.cs**

```cs
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureMauiHandlers(h =>
         {
             h.AddHandler<NamedEntry, EntryHandler>());
         });

    return builder.Build();
}
```

**Use in XAML**

```xml
<NamedEntry Text="{Binding StorageLocation}"
            Identifier="txtStorageLocation"
            StyleId="StorageLocation"
            Placeholder="{Binding LocationOrBinPlaceholder}"
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="20"/>
```

**Code behind**

```cs
public async void Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    var entry = (NamedEntry)sender;
    var fieldName = entry.Identifier;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In wpf there is a [tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property, you can implement a similar in MAUI as an attached property.

```
namespace Maui
{
    public class AttachedProperties
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty TagProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Tag", typeof(string), typeof(AttachedProperties), null);

        public static string GetTag(BindableObject bindable)
            => (string)bindable.GetValue(TagProperty);

        public static void SetTag(BindableObject bindable, string value)
            => bindable.SetValue(TagProperty, value);
    }
}
```

```
 <Entry    local:AttachedProperties.Tag="txtStorageLocation"
           Text="{Binding StorageLocation}"
           x:Name="txtStorageLocation"
           StyleId="StorageLocation"
           Placeholder="{Binding LocationOrBinPlaceholder}"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
           FontSize="20"/>
```

```
public async void Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    var entry = (Entry)sender;
    var fieldName = AttachedProperties.GetTag(entry);
}
```

---

An easier approach (but **ugly**) is to use [`ClassId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.element.classid?view=xamarin-forms). **Please be aware that the intended use case of this property is UI testing**.

Comment: Isn't ClassId used for UI tests?

Comment: this is not WPF

Comment: @FreakyAli yes but was thinking if it is not used for that purpose than you can use it it as an id, since i got downvoted i have completely changed the approach.

Comment: @ewerspej please read the whole answer.

Comment: I like this approach better, Upvote from me :)

Comment: Tag doesn't get passed in.  Neither does ClassId.  I tried both.  The only one that I (briefly) considered using was the base.Placeholder (which does pass back).  But I wouldn't want to use that as the user would see it.

Comment: oh, I see.  you're adding tag to an attached properties.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: That's a valid approach now, @Cfun

Comment: AttachedProperties worked!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found that in Maui, View.StyleId usually represents the name of the item, unless you explicitly change StyleId.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I created a better way to get all the named controls inside a Page. Named controls are stored as fields inside a page. So using Reflection:

```
public Dictionary<View, string> GetNamedControls(Page parent)
{
    Dictionary<View, string> namedControls = new();
    var fields = parent.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    foreach (var f in fields)
    {
        if (f.FieldType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(View)))
        {
            if (f.GetValue(parent) is View v)
                namedControls[v] = f.Name;
        }
    }
    return namedControls;
}
```